# gcc' failed with exit status - Python docker integration error

Tags: python, docker, gcc, docker-compose

I'm new to Python and trying to build a python application with Docker setup. 
When I try to build my docker (i.e. `docker build -t python-barcode`), I get the following error

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 (ss: https://www.screencast.com/t/Do1Bjkbo)

I tried to install `gcc`. I couldn't find any packages. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Dockerfile

```
 FROM python:3.6
    # Create app directory
    WORKDIR /app

    # Install app dependencies
    COPY src/requirements.txt ./

    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    RUN pip install zbar
    RUN pip install pyzbar
    # Bundle app source
    COPY src /app

    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD [ "python", "ocrApi.py" ]
```

`requirements.txt` file

```
flask
Pillow
pytesseract
opencv-python
requests
```

`ocrApi.py` file

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import pytesseract
#import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import cv2
import io,os
import requests
import urllib.request
import random
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\chethan\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at your output. Not `gcc` is missing but the header files for `zbar`.

So add extra

`RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y libzbar-dev`

to the Dockerfile before running `pip`.

Comment: Thank you so much @rocksportrocker. Its worked for me

Answer (score 1):

So the same error occurred to me also. I was using `python:3.6-alpine` and I upgraded it to `python:3.7-alpine`.Now, It is working fine without adding `libzbar-dev`.

Comment: For alpine based image `apk add linux-headers` should do the job